# Google Mobile Ads SDK caused segment fault 11 (xcode 7.3)

Tags: ios, xcode, admob

I am using AdMob sdk.
I got

```
1.  While loading members for 'ScheduleViewController' at <invalid loc>
2.  While deserializing decl #90 (PATTERN_BINDING_DECL)
3.  While deserializing decl #91 (VAR_DECL)
```

I slowly trace it down by commenting all new codes I added.
Then I found it's caused by

```
@IBOutlet weak var bannerView: GADBannerView!
```

Well then I don't have a good way to fix this line of code since it's simple and I have to use it without make code more complicated.

Any idea will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: when are you getting this error? I mean, at what stage of the lifecycle of your VC?

Comment: compile swift source files

Comment: merge swift module

Comment: Oh when you said segfault I thought it was at runtime, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I didn't uncomment use_frameworks in the pod file. No problem once it's in and updated.

Comment: I'm getting the same error but I don't see "use_frameworks" in my Podfile. Can you share your Podfile?